Why does macOS shell script create files with no permissions on an SMB server?
I am using the shell script VCS (Video Contact Sheet) by Toni Corvera, installed via Homebrew on macOS Sonoma.
When I use it to create contact sheets on local volumes, all works as expected, and the files are created with 644 permissions. However, if the output file is on an SMB file server, the image file is created with 000 permissions. Typical shell commands like touch create files on the same server with 644 permission.
Command line example:
/usr/local/bin/vcs -n 16 -H 240 -c 4 -j "/Volumes/Server/test.avi" -o "/Volumes/Server/test.jpg"

I have contacted the author, and he is unaware of what might cause the issue.
What could cause a bash script to create files with 000 permissions on an SMB server?
The script is more complicated than I am able to parse and figure out where the issue might be.
